# How to identify multiple different users on the same device under the same mixpanel project token?

Tags: android, mixpanel

I have multiple users on one Android device.

I am trying to use mixpanel, and I want each user to send their own app opened event.

I am doing

```
userIds.forEach {
        val mixpanelAPI = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(context,MIXPANEL_API_KEY)
       
        mixpanelAPI.people.identify(it)
        mixpanelAPI.identify(it)
           
        mixpanelAPI.flush()

}
```

But it does not seem to be working.
Any Idea ?